# Strange StringIndexOutofBoundsException caused when converting hex string to binary

Tags: java

I'm not sure what is causing this exception, and the stack trace isn't being helpful as it states it was caused by an unknown source.

The method below takes two hexadecimal strings, one representing an opcode and one representing an operand, and converts them to binary before concatenating them and adding them to an arraylist. Simple enough. In order to ensure each binary string includes the full 8 bits I'm using a small utility method called `hexToBinary`, for some reason, when I attempt to use this method to convert my hexadecimal strings it causes the exception.

The opcode and operands, which are taken from the asmLine objects give this input below:

```
A9 10
90 C6
0A 00
11 FF
38 00
7D FF
81 FF
A1 09
AA 00
20 11
58 00
6C 09
FE 10
```

All of the above hexadecimal values should be converted to binary. But this is not happening. The strange thing is that when I explicitly state the hexadecimal value to be converted by the utility method, as I do with the line `String beginBinary = Utils.hexToBinary("FA");` works completely normally. I just can't understand why this isn't working when I'm using the values pulled from the asmLine objects.

```
public void constructBinaryOutput()
    {
        ArrayList<String> binaryOut = new ArrayList<String>();

        String beginBinary = Utils.hexToBinary("FA"); //This works normally
        String endBinary = Utils.hexToBinary("FF");  //This works normally

        String twoByteString = beginBinary.concat(" " + beginBinary);

        binaryOut.add(twoByteString);

        for(AssemblyLine asmLine : lineObjects)
        {
            String opcodeHex = asmLine.getOpcodeHEX();
            String operandHex = asmLine.getOperandHEX();

            System.out.println("Hex opcode/operand: " + opcodeHex + " " + operandHex);

            String opcodeBinary = Utils.hexToBinary(opcodeHex); //This causes an exception
            String operandBinary = Utils.hexToBinary(operandHex); 

            System.out.println("Hex opcode " + asmLine.getOpcodeHEX() + " converted into binary " + opcodeBinary);
            System.out.println("Hex operand " + asmLine.getOperandHEX() + " converted into binary " + operandBinary);

            twoByteString = opcodeBinary.concat(" " + operandBinary);

            System.out.println("2 Byte instruction: " + twoByteString);

            binaryOut.add(twoByteString);
        }
}
```

Utility method `hexToBinary`

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex)
{
    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hex,16));
    int length = bin.length();
    return length == 8 ? bin : "00000000".substring(length - 8) + bin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple mistake in your util function. It should be:

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
        int length = bin.length();
        return length == 8 ? bin : "00000000".substring(length) + bin;
}
```

notice the substring.

HTH,
Gal